# bugfixer.bat batch file ask end user which option they want to run

Tags: batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

fun stuff!!

Manager has just bought a humdinger of a utility.  It does everything.  It even has command line functionality. If you run BugFixer /a the application will automatically scan the entire drive for cooties.  If you run the Bugfixer /b it will scan all of your files on the Windows\system 32 directory and if you run Bugfixer /c the program will scan and repair your Registry.  Need to write a batch file that will allow your users to avoid that pesky GUI and efficiently run the Bug fixer through the command line, by asking them which option they would like to initialize.

```
:TOP 
ECHO WHICH BUG FIXER DO YOU NEED TO RUN? A=ALL B=SOME c=REPAIR 
SET /P = %USERSPEC% 
IF "%1"=="A=ALL" GO TO :FIRST 
IF "%1"=="A=all" GO TO :FIRST 
:FIRST
CHKDSK C:
ECHO CHECKING ALL FILES ARE COMPLETE 
IF "%2"=="B=SOME" GO TO :NEXT
IF "%2"=="b=some" GO TO :NEXT 
:NEXT 
CHKDSK /F /R C:\WINDOWS/SYSTEM32 
ECHO CHECKING SOME FILES ARE COMPLETE 
IF "%3"=="REPAIR" GO TO :LAST 
IF "%3"=="repair" GO TO :LAST 
:LAST
CHKDSK /c 
ECHO REPAIR FILES ARE COMPLETED
```

Like I said fun stuff.  Anyone wanna help?

Comment: Can you post at least the code source of this Bugfixer.bat ??

Comment: chkdsk.  Here is what I have so far...needs tweaks.     As you can see Im new at this.                    :TOP
ECHO WHICH BUG FIXER DO YOU NEED TO RUN? A=ALL B=SOME c=REPAIR
SET  /P = %USERSPEC%
IF "%1"=="A=ALL"GO TO :FIRST
IF "%1"=="A=all"GO TO :FIRST
:FIRST 
CHKDSK C:
ECHO CHECKING ALL FILES ARE COMPLETE
IF "%2"=="B=SOME"GO TO :NEXT
IF "%2"=="b=some"GO TO :NEXT
:NEXT 
CHKDSK /F /R C:\WINDOWS/SYSTEM32
ECHO CHECKING SOME FILES ARE COMPLETE
IF "%3"=="REPAIR"GO TO :LAST
IF "%3"=="repair"GO TO :LAST
:LAST 
CHKDSK /c
ECHO REPAIR FILES ARE COMPLETED

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in comments (become quite unreadable). [edit] your question rather... See my attempt, [edit] if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next script *logic* could become helpful:

```
@echo OFF >NUL
setlocal enableextensions
:TOP
echo(
set "USERSPEC="
set /P "USERSPEC=Which bug fixer do you need to run? A=all B=some C=repair? "
if /I "%USERSPEC%"=="A" goto :FIRST 
if /I "%USERSPEC%"=="B" goto :NEXT  
if /I "%USERSPEC%"=="C" goto :LAST
echo NO CHECK CHOOSEN, BATCH ENDS
goto :ENDSCRIPT

:FIRST
chkdsk C:
echo CHECKING ALL FILES ARE COMPLETE 
goto :TOP

:NEXT 
chkdsk /F /R C:\WINDOWS/SYSTEM32 
echo CHECKING SOME FILES ARE COMPLETE 
goto :TOP

:LAST
chkdsk /c 
echo REPAIR FILES ARE COMPLETED
goto :TOP

:ENDSCRIPT
endlocal
goto :eof
```

However, running it:

```
==>30019117.bat

Which bug fixer do you need to run? A=all B=some C=repair? a
Access Denied as you do not have sufficient privileges.
You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode.
CHECKING ALL FILES ARE COMPLETE

Which bug fixer do you need to run? A=all B=some C=repair?
NO CHECK CHOOSEN, BATCH ENDS

==>
```

**Resources** (advised reading):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) (command reference)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) (additional particularities)
- [Script resources for IT professionals](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search) (a huge Script repository)

Comment: THANK YOU!  VERY GRATEFUL FOR YOUR KNOWLEDGE...AS YOU CAN SEE I WAS NOWHERE CLOSE.

Comment: Here is one more if you get bored tonight.